# is the time complexity of binary search log n?

Tags: algorithm

How is the time complexity of binary search logn. It should be n because of number of steps. I am confused.

So according to definition of time complexity its the number of steps so it should be n.Can anyone clarify for me?

Comment: This is not about `dsa` (Digital Signature Algorithm).

Answer (score 0):

Binary search is used on a sorted array. If we define  as the size of that array, then the binary search algorithm has a time complexity of O(log).

To analyse this, let's take this iterative pseudo code as provided on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm):

```pascal
function binary_search(A, n, T) is
    L := 0
    R := n − 1
    while L ≤ R do
        m := floor((L + R) / 2)
        if A[m] < T then
            L := m + 1
        else if A[m] > T then
            R := m − 1
        else:
            return m
    return unsuccessful
```

If we define a *step* as one iteration of the loop, then there are at most 1+⌊log<sub><sub>2</sub></sub>⌋ steps. The worst case scenario happens when the target value  is not found in . Let's take an example:

```
A = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14]
n = 7
T = 5
```

We can follow the state of each variable at the moment `m` is assigned its value in each iteration (one row in the table):

| iteration | L | R | m | A[m] |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 6 | 3 | 8 |
| 2 | 0 | 2 | 1 | 4 |
| 3 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 6 |

After the third iteration the loop exits. So there are 3 iterations. Yet our array  has 7 entries, so not every value in the array was inspected. Every iteration the "window" (with  and  as its boundaries) halves in size. The values in the other half are discarded. So starting with a window of 7 values, this is reduced in one iteration to 3 values, then 1 value, each time halfing the number of potential candidates.

Answer (score 0):

Each iteration of binary search eliminates half the remaining array. After doing this O(log n) times, we've eliminated everything but our answer, if it's in the array.